# Problema con instrucción if/ else

Tags: python, condiciones

Soy principiante y estoy dificultades para resolver el siguiente problema:

Érase una vez una tierra - una tierra de leche y miel, habitada por gente feliz y próspera. La gente pagaba impuestos, por supuesto, su felicidad tenía límites. El impuesto más importante, denominado Impuesto Personal de Ingresos (IPI, para abreviar) tenía que pagarse una vez al año y se evaluó utilizando la siguiente regla:

- Si el ingreso del ciudadano no era superior a 85,528 pesos, el impuesto era igual al 18% del ingreso menos 556 pesos y 2 centavos (esta fue la llamada exención fiscal ).
- Si el ingreso era superior a esta cantidad, el impuesto era igual a 14,839 pesos y 2 centavos, más el 32% del excedente sobre 85,528 pesos.

Tu tarea es escribir una calculadora de impuestos.

Debe aceptar un valor de punto flotante: el ingreso.

A continuación, debe imprimir el impuesto calculado, redondeado a pesos totales. Hay una función llamada round() que hará el redondeo por ti, la encontrarás en el código de esqueleto del editor.

Nota: Este país feliz nunca devuelve dinero a sus ciudadanos. Si el impuesto calculado es menor que cero, solo significa que no hay impuesto (el impuesto es igual a cero). Ten esto en cuenta durante tus cálculos.

Observa el código en el editor: solo lee un valor de entrada y genera un resultado, por lo que debes completarlo con algunos cálculos inteligentes.

Prueba tu código con los datos que hemos proporcionado.

**Datos de prueba**

> Entrada de muestra: 10000
>
> Resultado esperado: El impuesto es: 1244.0 pesos
>
> Entrada de muestra: 100000
>
> Resultado esperado: El impuesto es: 19470.0 pesos
>
> Entrada de muestra: 1000
>
> Resultado esperado: El impuesto es: 0.0 pesos
>
> Entrada de muestra: -100
>
> Resultado esperado: El impuesto es: 0.0 pesos

Ya realice la mayor parte:

```
ingreso=float(input("Ingrese el ingreso anual:"))

if ingreso <= 85528:
    impuesto = ingreso * .18 - 556.02
    

else:
    ingreso >85529
    impuesto = 14839 + (ingreso - 85528) * .32

    

impuesto=round(impuesto, 0)
print("El impuesto es: ", impuesto, "pesos")
```

Lo qué me esta costando trabajo es que si el impuesto es negativo o cero, imprima:

```
El impuesto es:0.0 pesos
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ingreso=float(input("Ingrese el ingreso anual:"))

if ingreso <= 85528:
   impuesto = ingreso * .18 - 556.02


else:
  ingreso >85529
  impuesto = 14839 + (ingreso - 85528) * .32

if impuesto<0:
 impuesto=0

impuesto=round(impuesto, 0)
print("El impuesto es: ", impuesto, "pesos")
```

Yo lo haria de esta forma. Antes de la impresion del valor que contiene la variable impuesto verificaria si este tiene un valor negativo. Si es asi lo transformaria a 0. En caso de que impuesto sea cero el valor ya se imprimiria como cero.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte y ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
income = float(input("Introduce el ingreso anual:"))        
if income <=3089:   #valor absoluto de -556.02/.18 para conocer el menor valor para que no den valores negativos  
    income =0.0        
elif income < 85528:        
    income = (income*(0.18)-556.02)        
else:        
    income > 855280        
    income= (income -14839.02)*0.32        
income= round(income, 0)        
print("El impuesto es:", income, "pesos")
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

deseo te ayude.

```
ingreso=float(input("Ingrese el ingreso anual:"))

if ingreso <= 85528:
    impuesto = ((ingreso*0.18)-556.2)
else: 
    ingreso > 85528
    impuesto = (14839+0.2) + ((ingreso-85528)*0.32)
if impuesto <0:
    impuesto = 0.0

impuesto=round(impuesto, 0)
print("El impuesto es: ", impuesto, "pesos")
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código.

Comment: seria ideal que explicaras tu respuesta